# Why does getWorkInfosForUniqueWork() return a list of WorkInfo when it's supposed to be unique?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

Is there a chance that the list will ever include more than one WorkInfo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. As per the [unique work documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work):

> Unlike [tags](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/define-work#tag), unique names are only associated with one chain of work.

So if you are [chaining work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/chain-work) or using [`ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ExistingWorkPolicy.html#APPEND) (which implicitly is adding the new item to the end of the chain of current work), then multiple `WorkInfo` objects will be returned.

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake!